# Azure Batch : How to set static IP for nodes

Tags: azure-batch

How do we set static IP for the nodes in Azure Batch jobs. Out batch job needs to access our sql server during the batch job. Our SQL server is on a Classic VM with ACL on. Due to this we need to add IP to the SQL server ACL so that the batch job can access it. Should I use "Batch service" or "User Subscription"?

Comment: Can you please add a scenario and why the setting of static IP is in need? Any details will be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: I have a batch job which pull data from MS SQL and does some processing and then writes to another data base once a day. The MS SQL DB is behind an ACL(Access Control List ) so the DB only accept requests from predefined IPs. If the batch job keeps changing the IP each time it would not be able to communicate with MS SQL.

Comment: Can you put Batch pool in the same VNet as your SQL server? With UserSubscription Batch accounts, Batch supports specifying a Subnet during pool creation. Would that be sufficient for your requirement

Comment: Unfortunately the the MS SQL server was created longtime back using classic VM  and is under classic Vnet. If i read properly UserSubscription uses the new ARM Vnet. so I cannot put the nodes in the same VNet as MS SQL DB

Comment: Can you use CloudServiceconfiguration based pools which supports Classic VNet (They will have to use regular Batch accounts though, not Usersubscription accounts).

Comment: From the UI when I Select Add Pool  Network Configuration is disabled. How do i set the node to be in Classic VNet?

Comment: Please see this related question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51987941/4896852).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Batch Account Static IP Addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987418/azure-batch-account-static-ip-addresses)