# Azure Batch Account Static IP Addresses

Tags: azure, static-ip-address, azure-batch, virtual-ip-address

I am needing to set a range of static remote desktop ip addresses for Azure Batch nodes within a pool. Is this even possible given the node will enter and exit the pool on occasion?

I have viewed documentation but have not had luck. Is this even possible? How can this be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer 2019-09-09:

You can now specify static public IPs provisioned via Azure Resource Manager (ARM) as part of a VirtualMachineConfiguration-based pool allocation. Please see the [networkConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/pool/add#networkconfiguration) property of the Pool Add operation. You will need to ensure that the public IP resource ids specified are not currently in use and are from within the same region and subscription id as the Batch account.

Comment: Is there documentation to support this? Anything helps!

Comment: This is a feature request that is currently under consideration, but there is no ETA. You can "force" all compute nodes to have a single IP address that will not change through resizes for the pool by setting the `enableInterNodeCommunication` on the pool to `true`. This will force the pool to use a single underlying deployment, but will limit the maximum number of nodes which varies upon the pool configuration type chosen. Note that this is strictly a current workaround and such behavior is not guaranteed to work in the future.